# Приоритет операций при парсинге с помощью PLY

Tags: python, парсер

Пишу парсер Си-подобного языка и столкнулся с проблемой. Вот мой парсер, если из него удалить всё лишнее, что не относится к ошибке:

```
from ply import lex, yacc

tokens = ('LT', 'LPAREN', 'RPAREN', 'NAME')

t_NAME = r'[A-Za-z_@][A-Za-z0-9_@]*'
t_LPAREN = r'\('
t_RPAREN = r'\)'
t_LT = r'<'

t_ignore = ' '

precedence = (
    ('left', 'LT'),
    ('left', 'CALL')
)

def p_expression_binop(p):
    'expression : expression LT expression'
    p[0] = (p[2], p[1], p[3])

def p_expression_call(p):
    'expression : expression LPAREN RPAREN %prec CALL'
    p[0] = ('Call', p[1])

def p_expression_name(p):
    'expression : NAME'
    p[0] = ('Name', p[1])

lexer = lex.lex()
parser = yacc.yacc()
print(parser.parse('a < b()'))
```

Если запустить данный пример, то можно получить что-то вроде (пробелы и отступы добавлены для читабельности):

```
[
    ('Call',
        ('<',
            ('Name', 'a'),
            ('Name', 'b')
        )
    )
]
```

Как можно заметить, операция сравнения почему-то оказалась более приоритетной, чем операция вызова функции, в результате мы пытаемся сравнить переменную (a) и функцию (b), а затем вызвать результат сравнения, что некорректно. Я бы хотел получить сначала вызов функции, а уже потом сравнение её результата и переменной.

В то же время я вроде как явно задал приоритет ( по сравнению с <, как это указано в документации http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn27 (там, правда, пример с приоритетом умножения над сложением, что в полной версии моей грамматики тоже отлично работает).

PLY не выводит никаких предупреждений о конфликтах в грамматике.

В чём моя ошибка и как её исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки нет и получать сначала вызов функции не нужно, потому что это будет против логики обхода синтаксического дерева. Разберем строку:

```
a < b()
[root]
   |- <
      |- a
      |- b() --> вызов
```

то есть распознается и отображается оно верно. Значит, нельзя дойти до `b()`, не пройдя `<`. Поэтому синтаксический анализатор распознает сначала `a` (или не распознает и упадет), потом `b()`. А вызов функции сможет получить только интерпретатор (хотя его можно встроить, как показано в примере с калькулятором).

Поэтому ошибка в желании, а не в коде.

Comment: В вопросе дерево для: `(a < b)()`, а нужно чтобы было: `(a) < (b())`. Правильный вывод: `('<', ('Name', 'a'),  ('Call', ('Name', 'b'))) `